# SQL-Script request performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I found the following SQL-script integrated in an web-AppCode.
How would be the following SQL-Script from the performance side effective rewrite ?

Below I attached also the execution plan. Is there the Nested Loop the biggest problem?

```
with x as (
select 
CM_Customer.BSTNR, CM_Customer.AUFTRAGSDATUM

from
CM_Customer
except (
    select 
    distinct
    CM_Customer.BSTNR, 
    CM_Customer.AUFTRAGSDATUM
    from 
        CRX.dbo.DimDateBST
        INNER JOIN CRX.dbo.CM_Customer ON DimDateBST.BSTNR=CM_Customer.BSTNR and DimDateBST.DatCal=CM_Customer.AUFTRAGSDATUM    )
)


SELECT * from CM_Customer 
  where BSTNR not in
(
select distinct x.BSTNR from x 

)
```

[image: Exec plan]

Comment: Can you post the actual execution plan instead of a picture? There is a LOT of information more than the picture in that file. And if performance is the issue we need more than just the execution plan. Table definitions and indexes.

Comment: @SeanLange do you mean the xml code related to the execution plan?

Comment: What you are trying to do? Why you are using DISTINCT in not in subquery? What is your input and what is your expected output?

Comment: Please add an explanation of what it is you are trying to achieve. Your query looks really circuitous, I would guess there's an easier way to write the query. But that would require a clear statement on what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @KannanKandasamy it's not my query. In my opinion thic could be simple rewrite like this  SELECT cm.*
 FROM 
 [CRX].[dbo].[CM_Customer] cm
  inner join DimDateBST bst on bst.DatCal=cm.AUFTRAGSDATUM and cm.BSTNR=bst.BSTNR

Comment: @TT. I think the owner just tried to retrieve the rows from CM_Customer only if the fields BSTNR and AUFTRAGSDATUM have a corresponding in DimDateBST.  I think a simple inner join DimDateBST bst on bst.DatCal=cm.AUFTRAGSDATUM and cm.BSTNR=bst.BSTNR  would do the same logic...